# Function that has per MacLaurin series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

What is the function of the MacLaurin series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$$

I think is a complex function, but I have no idea how to start. Is it already discovered?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4719032/edit)): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This series has a rather simple expression in terms of inverse trigonometric and inverse hyperbolic functions, so I'd recommend try to find it yourself. If you are not able to solve it, post your efforts and you'll probably get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n}$$
This is just a geometric series, with common ratio $x^4$ and hence provided $|x^4|<1$ we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^4}$$
Hence
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(s)\mathrm ds=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-s^4}\mathrm ds$$
As given by Guillermo.

Introduce a partial fraction decomposition:
$$\frac{1}{1-s^4}=\frac{1}{(1+s^2)(1-s^2)} \\ =\frac{A}{1+s^2}+\frac{B}{1-s^2}$$
We see that
$$(1+s^2)B+(1-s^2)A=1 \\ B+A+s^2(B-A)=1$$
This means that we must have $B=A=1/2$. Therefore

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+s^2}\mathrm ds+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-s^2}\mathrm ds$$
Which, assuming $x\in(0,1)$, is
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\arctan(x)+\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\big)}$$

Answer (score 3):

This function is $$f(x) =\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t^4}dt.$$ Why? Give it a try.

Comment: Obtaining a closed form is not difficult. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, i Know. I give this form to not make too easy for the guy of the question.